# Git - Replace repository code with code from another repository on BitBucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have three repositories for my code base.

Master - contains code used for production
Dev - contains code currently in development 
Admin - contains code for the admin panel

I'm trying to configure my dev repository and right now the code in the Master repo is much further along than in the Dev repo.  I want to copy back the code from the master to the dev repo and then develop in the dev repo.  Then I eventually want to be able to push those changes in the master repo when I am done.  I can't figure out how to do this.  Please help!

Comment: did you try to use branch?

Comment: Why three repositories?  Isn't that the point of branches?

Comment: I'm mainly using three repos to leverage my auto deploy script to push it to the server which looks for changes on separate repos

Comment: pull from master repo, push to dev repo. what's the problem?